# Em python, como posso simular uma propriedade somente-leitura em classes?

Tags: python, classes, propriedade

Eu gostaria de saber como posso simular uma propriedade somente leitura em `Python`.

Por exemplo, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
class IPInfo(object):
     def __init__(self, ip):
         self.ip = ip;


ip = IPInfo(object)

ip.ip = 'aqui é possível editar, mas quero desabilitar isso';

print ip.ip #aqui é possível imprimir, pois a leitura é permitida
```

Como eu poderia tornar a propriedade `ip` somente-leitura?

Comment: Creio que não dá, digo isto apoiado aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-to-create-a-constant-in-python

Comment: @Miguel dá sim :p.

Comment: Ok, se for com decorators dá

Comment: Isso mesmo, hehehehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare uma propriedade `getter-only`, usando o decorator **`@property`**

```
class IPInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, ip):
        self._ip = ip;

    @property
    def ip (self):
        return self._ip


ip = IPInfo(object)

ip.ip = 'aqui é possível editar, mas quero desabilitar isso';
#A linha acima vai estourar um erro - AttributeError: can't set attribute    

print ip.ip
```

Comment: No caso não seria um duplo underline?

Comment: Em **`self._ip`**?

Comment: é ...............

Comment: Poderia dar um exmplo prático jbueno sff. Testei aqui mas não sei como definir/imprimir a 'constante', o resultado que obtenho é `<property object at 0x7feaa22bb818>`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Na verdade, acho que não, mas não tenho certeza. Acho que seguindo a convenção de nomes do Python, é um underline só.

Comment: @jbueno é verdade. Quando se usa dois, você está indicando uma funcionalidade especial.

Comment: @Miguel Pronto, tô tentando salvar um fiddle

Comment: Obrigado jbueno